# function to check POST multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following function to check the array's keys

```
public function check($arr, $key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($arr[$key]) && !empty($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $default;
}


$this->check($info, 'location'); //it's working
$this->check($info['birthday'], 'year'); //it's working
$this->check($_POST, 'email'); //it's working
$this->check($_POST, 'password'); //it's working
```

everything is ok until multidimensional array appears

[image]

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in
```

Comment: Then why not check if the `$key` value is a array (`is_array();`), if it is, go a level deeper, check again for array, if array go deeper. (And of course if it's not an' array then you just check the value)

Comment: And also if you are using `empty()`, I think there is no need for `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what are you looking for but please notice that if you have email[][] field, when you return $arr[$key] you are returning an array. So you have to check if $arr[$key] is an array before returning its value.

```
public function check($arr, $key, $default = NULL) {
    if( isset($arr[$key]) && !empty($arr[$key]) || is_array($arr[$key])) { 

       if(is_array($arr[$key])) { 
         //apply here your second level check condition

       } else return $arr[$key]; // returns its value (if it's not an array)


    } else return $default;
}
```

Hope it  helps

Instead, if you're trying to build a function checking recursively if $key is contained somewhere in a multidimensional array, you have to do otherwise (that's why I wrote I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

change your function code to:

```
public function check($arr, $key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : $default;
}
```

if you still want to check for empty value (though isset is enough):

```
public function check($arr, $key, $default = NULL) {
    return isset($arr[$key]) && (!empty($arr[$key]) || is_array($arr[$key])) ? $arr[$key] : $default;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 ? $arr[$key]
```

In the above code you are using `$_POST['email']` (which is an array) as a string.

Comment: I don't think you read OP's question properly (FYI I didn't down vote)

Comment: down vote should be accompanied by a comment. Thanks